# "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."

Tags: c#

Having this issue with a program that adds files through a form to a txt file but the issue doesn't say anything about Fstream so i'm thinking it doesn't have to deal with it but i'm not sure what this problem means.

```
lstEmployees.Items.Add("No records found.");
```

Comment: First, check if you have any data binding in place, and remove it. Before you add items, de-assign the data source explicitly, i.e. `lstEmployees.DataSource = null;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message tells us that you have set the "DataSource property" on "lstEmployees".
So go to "lstEmployees" properties and remove the DataSource - or if you want to keep the DataSource, don´t try to add "your own" items to "lstEmployees", as it won´t be accepted.

Answer (score 22):

Once you add a .DataSource to your listbox, you cannot modify the ListBox.Items collection.  Instead, you can modify the original source.

For example, if your listbox is bound to a generic list of strings:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Item 1");
myList.Add("Item 2");
myList.Add("Item 3");

myListBox.DataSource = myList;

// need to add an item to the list after it's bound
myList.Add("No records found.");
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's telling you that you can't do an `Items.Add()` to lstEmployees when you've set the `DataSource` on lstEmployees and called `DataBind()`.

Without more code I can't say more.