# add/remove List<> items selected in a ListBox

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I have two Lists, the firs (right) represents a list of all cars and the secound (left) a list of cars for sale.

There are two ListBoxes at my control, each of them will display one of the cars list. I want to click a button (<<) and the selected car at the ListBox 1 will be added to the ListBox 1 list.

The two lists are created outside the control class, so I need to bind then to the ListBoxes. I have tried to use DataSource but I can not use Add Remove from Items if I set it. Which is the best way to do that?

[image]

Thanks.

OBS: Ive changed to a ListBox.

---

The solution that I'm using is: Very very ugly solution... :/

```
    public IList<Item> ItensToMaintaim
    {
        get { return (IList<Item>)this.itensToMainTainList.DataSource; }
        set
        {
            //Need to set null to refresh
            this.itensToMainTainList.DataSource = null;
            this.itensToMainTainList.DataSource = value;
            this.itensToMainTainList.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.itensToMainTainList.ValueMember = "Name";
        }
    }

    public IList<Item> Itens
    {
        get { return (IList<Item>)this.itensList.DataSource; }
        set
        {
            //Need to set null to refresh
            this.itensList.DataSource = null;
            this.itensList.DataSource = value;
            this.itensList.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.itensList.ValueMember = "Name";
        }
    }

    private void removeItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.itensToMainTainList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            this.itens2.Remove((Item)this.itensToMainTainList.SelectedItem);
            this.ItensToMaintaim = this.itens2;
            if (this.itensToMainTainList.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                this.itensToMainTainList.SelectedIndex = this.itens2.Count - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.itensList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            bool contains = false;
            contains = this.itens2.Contains(this.itensList.SelectedItem);
            if (!contains)
            {
                this.itens2.Add((Item)this.itensList.SelectedItem);
                this.ItensToMaintaim = this.itens2;
            }
            if (this.itensList.SelectedIndex < this.itens1.Count - 1)
            {
                this.itensList.SelectedIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to set DataSource and remove items from the list itself?

Comment: Yes, but once I set DataSource, it does not updates anymore, If I change the orignal list, the combobox still displaing the old one, Ive tried to reset DataSource, but nothing changes.

Comment: Which type of windows app you using? (Winform / SilverLight etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the DataSource, you can not add items to that collection.

["Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035744/items-collection-cannot-be-modified-when-the-datasource-property-is-set)

But you can do it with some workarounds

**1)** Save to database and load it again with new values and bind it

OR

**2)** Get the exising data source of the Listbox and store it in a varaiable and add a new item (which is created from the selected item) and then re bind it again

Example ( the classes are specific to my need, you can customize based on your class structure)

```
    //Take the existing
    List<MailerKit> objExisting = (List<MailerKit>)comboBox1.DataSource;
    //Add the new one
    objExisting.Add(new MailerKit { KitName = comboBox1.SelectedText, ID = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue) });

    //Rebind again
    comboBox1.DataSource = objExisting;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "KitName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: Rebinding the datasource is what I was missing. DataSource = null and DataSource = myList.

Comment: @Pedro77: glad it iw sowking for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom events for adding and removing items in the lists. Handle these events in your control class where you have defined the comboboxes to add or remove their items.

Comment: You mean make a public event at the control and bind it to add/remove items. Yes it is one possibility, but I'm tring to change the List inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

Bind lists with datasource, as you did. Then remove and add items to lists, not to combobox itselves.