# Adding new items to binded listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, bindingsource

I have a listbox "listBox_users" binded to a bindingsource, and another listbox "listBox_map" which is binded also. I want to drag and drop a user from listBox_users to listBox_map.I have done this very well when i delete the bindingsource of listBox_map.
My problem is that the listBox_map don't add new items when data source property is defined:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

```
 private void listBox_map_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string str = listBox_users.Text;

             listBox_map.Items.Add(str); // Error here!
        }

    }
```

How can i add new items to binded listbox?
Thank you.

Comment: Add items to the datasource instead of use listBox_map.Items.Add.

Comment: You can view this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035744/items-collection-cannot-be-modified-when-the-datasource-property-is-set

Comment: I have seen that but he said " remove the DataSource" and i have to keep it.

Comment: Use BindingSource.Add method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use

```
  listBox_map.Items.Add(str); // Error here!
```

Do it:

```
yourBindingSourceReference.Add(str);
```

It will automatically reflect on your listBox_map.

[MSDN - BindingSource.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by myself, so i deleted the datasource property and i added every row in the listbox:

```
var q = 
            from user in SundicappEntities.Instance.users
                join map in SundicappEntities.Instance.user_profile_map on user.id_user equals map.id_user 
                where map.id_profile==id_profile
                select new
                {

                             ListBoxItemDisplayText = user.name_user + " " + user.f_name_user     

                };
        foreach (var u in q)
        {
             listBox_map.Items.Add(u.ListBoxItemDisplayText); 
        }
```